# How do I access my app page settings in Facebook again?

Tags: android, facebook

I followed the instructions in the android tutorial and registered 2 native android apps in facebook.  I got the ID, and so far as I remember, I put the key in as well.

I'm having errors with it now, so I'm trying to get back in and verify that I put the correct value in for the key...but I cannot get to any page that holds that info.  Most links that I've followed so far just take me back to my facebook "Your pages" page, which has my account page, and a page for each of the two apps I've already registered.  No link anywhere in those app pages takes me to where the key value is registered.

Even trying to create another app entry, via the tutorial, and following this link:

https://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php

just takes me directly to:

http://www.facebook.com/browse/admined_pages/?id=1000.....

I can't imagine how this could be any more frustrating....

Comment: Do you not see the applications that you created at http://developers.facebook.com/ under the Apps link?

Comment: When I click that link (and am already logged into Facebook), it takes me to the generic developers Facebook page, and if I click on Apps on the upper bar, then it takes me to a facebook page that says "Your Pages", and lists my developer facebook page, and a page for each app I've created.  But clicking on those links for those pages just takes me to the app page, and on those app pages I can't find any place to access the app ID or key info.

Comment: On mine it very distinctly displays the App_ID and APP_secret for every application that I've created.  You're sure that you created the apps with the facebook account that you are using?  I know it's an obvious question, but it's all I can think of that would prevent you from seeing (and configuring) your own applications.

Comment: Yes, definitely the account I registered the apps with...I've still got the facebook confirmation emails in my inbox.  Should I not have created pages for those apps?  I think creating the app "PAGE" is different than having registered/created the app itself.  Maybe I should delete those pages, since they don't contain much info anyway.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the pages I had created, and that didn't make any difference.  I basically can't access the "create an app" page at all...it just takes me to my facebook page.  I noticed that when I logged in with a different account, I could access that page.  So I don't understand why my company facebook account can't access the app pages.

Comment: So by following this URL:  http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=<APP_ID>&v=wall  and inserting my app ID in there, I was able to access the page for the app.  And I got to settings, and from there I found Edit App, and then App Settings...woohoo, so close to paydirt!  But I click Edit...and it once again takes me to my main facebook page.  In fact, I can see about 5 different facebook addresses flash through the URL as it redirects me.  So bottom line is that I still cannot access my app settings.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  It was under known "bugs".  Apparently they allowed people to create business facebook accounts, and register apps under those accounts...and then regretted doing it, and so silently disabled all app access through those accounts.  Yay, thanks guys.  Here is the url that describes the problem and where to go to assign your apps (via the ID) to your regular-human facebook account.  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/133607873418215

Comment: The "Bug" link doesn't work, it loads as the main Bugs page. I'm finding I'm in the same situation though...  On the bugs page, any article I click forwards me back(?) to the same /admined_pages page (as does any link on that page itself, like "settings").